# ElasticSearch: Matching multiple queries

Tags: ruby, lucene, elasticsearch, tire

I am using Tire (ElasticSearch Ruby gem), and want to match a few fields on the keyword "community marketing". However, I also want ElasticSearch to return me results for the keyword "communities marketing" as well. The standard analyzer does not parse/tokenize "communities" as "community" so they're separate keywords.

How do I get ElasticSearch to return me results for both "community marketing" and "communities marketing"? I prefer to do this in query time, rather than index time. I'm fine with ElasticSearch standard analyzer and prefer not to mess around with it.

```
fields = ["title", "popular_hash_tags"]
keyword = "communities marketing"
keyword2 = "community marketing"

s = Tire.search "articles" do
    query do
        match fields, keyword, :operator => "AND"
        #NOW I also want to match keyword2??
    end
end
```

Comment: you say you don't want to deal with changing analyzers, but it sounds like you should certainly consider it.  This sort of case is a typical reason to have a stemmer.  The [`english` analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html) should take care of this for you.  I deals with plurals and other suffixes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest digging through the query DSL of Elasticsearch. You will find a lot of interesting stuff.
For instance, the "should" clause of a bool filter.
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-filter.html